# Is the function differentiable on the entire real line?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Ok so I know this question has been asked multiple times but in a slightly different format;
Consider the function defined by:
$$f(x)=x^2 \sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)~\text{for}~x \neq0$$
$$f(x)=0~\text{for}~x=0$$

Using the limit derivative definition I found:
$$f_R'(0^+)=0~\text{and}~f_L'(0^-)=0$$
By means of the squeeze theorem, but that:
$$f'(x)=2x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)-\frac{2\cos\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{x}~\text{for}~x\neq0$$
So that using this formula we can see that $f'(0^+)$ and $f'(0^-)$ DNE.
However I nor anybody else in my class were deducted full points for saying that the derivative exists for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Can anybody please clarify why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When $h\neq 0$ then $$\left|\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}\right|=\left|h\sin\left(\frac1{h^2}\right)\right|\leq|h|.$$

So, letting $h\to 0,$ $f’(0)=0.$

This is a classic example of a function differentiable everywhere with a derivative that is not continuous.

Answer (score 4):

The derivative exists in all $x$, but $f'$ is not  continuous at $0$.